# Is there a way to know how many images have been processed during the training process?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

When training a CNN with TensorFlow's Object Detection API, is there a way to know how many images have been processed during the training process?

I don't see anything in TensorBoard other than the basic scalars (Total Loss, etc.). The command line training process shows the step number, but I'm not sure if that correlates to the number of images processed or which ones it's actually processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of images processed is equal to the step number times the batch size.